# Class to Class Access Data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-widget

I have a problem with classes. I keep the user data in user_info_screen with Google auth. How can I pull this user data in a class that has this data on another page?

```
 class UserInfoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   UserInfoScreen({Key key, User user})
      : _user = user,
        super(key: key);

  final User _user;

  @override
  _UserInfoScreenState createState() => _UserInfoScreenState();
}

class _UserInfoScreenState extends State<UserInfoScreen> {

  User _user;
```

The page I want to use (user) by pulling this data

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle it, espacially if you will use the user data on other pages, is to implement a store concept : https://pub.dev/packages/get

**UserInfoScreen.dart**

```
GetStorage box = GetStorage();
box.write('userData', _user);
```

**HomeView.dart**

```
GetStorage box = GetStorage();
User _user = box.read('userData');
```

---

Or pass it as an argument

**UserInfoScreen.dart**

```
Get.to(() => HomeView(), arguments: [
    {"userData": _user}
]);
```

**HomeView.dart**

```
  dynamic argumentData = Get.arguments;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print(argumentData[0]['userData']);
    super.onInit();
  }
```

Comment: its working good thank you, but I'm getting this error and user's displayname return null ------[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'User' ------ anyway I can see user.dispname after hot restart. how can I solve this?

Comment: @Ferhat37ozkan you might need to add a not null condition when you manipulate the user object, or work with asynchronous process to wait that user data.